# cant fix RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice

Tags: discord.py

I've already installed the `PyNaCl` module but I still can't fix this error

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "TOKEN"
PREFIX = '-'
#client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX) 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    print(channel)
    await channel.connect()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

The code runs perfectly with other commands.

Comment: Can you make sure that `PyNaCl` is installed by doing `pip freeze` and making sure that it is listed there.

Comment: Make sure to install ```PyNaCl```. ```pip install pynacl```